# Receiving `Login timeout expired` when connecting to a serverless Azure Synapse SQL pool using `ActiveDirectoryPassword` authentication and pyodbc

Tags: azure, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I'm trying to run Azure Synapse SQL queries on a serverless SQL pool from Python using pyodbc. I'm trying to authenticate with an Azure Active Directory user. Here is my code:

```py
import pyodbc

driver = '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
server = '<server>'
db = '<db>'
username = '<user>@<domain>@<synapse-workspace>'
password = '<password>'

with pyodbc.connect(
    f'Driver={driver};Server=tcp:{server},1433;Database={db};Uid={username};Pwd={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;') as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()  
    cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 100 * from foo') 
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        print(row) 
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I'm pretty stumped because I'm able to sign in with the same username and password to both the Synapse Workspace and Azure Data Studio.

Any ideas what's wrong? Or any ideas for how to get a more helpful error message?

UPDATE:

I increased the timeout and received a different error:

```
pyodbc.Error: ('FA004', '[FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user \'<user>@<domain>@<synapse-workspace>\' in Active Directory (Authentication option is \'ActiveDirectoryPassword\').\nError code 0xA190; state 41360\n{"ver":"1.0","account_type":"Unknown","cloud_instance_name":"microsoftonline.com","cloud_audience_urn":"urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline"}\nUnknown account type. (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: hi @alexlod, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999152/unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-odbc-using-python/75002260#75002260)

Comment: Thanks @SaiVamsi but downgrading to version 17 didn't help. Plus, that example shows how to connect with a SQL user and password vs I'm trying to use Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The time out error is generally come because the server is not responding.

- Two solutions you can try extending connection timeout period in connection string.
  --  The default value is 30 seconds.
  -- A value of 0 means to wait indefinitely and never time out.
- Try by Downgrade the ODBC driver version to 17 or 13.

Or the work around is to use the `ActiveDirectoryInteractive`

```py
import pyodbc

server =  '<servername>'
database =  '<database name>'
username =  '<loginId>'
password =  '<password>'
driver=  '{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}'
Authentication='ActiveDirectoryInteractive'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
'DRIVER='+driver+
';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+
';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+
';UID='+username+
';Authentication='+Authentication)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik but unfortunately none of these suggestions worked. I tried a timeout of 300 seconds, tried downgrading to 17, wasn't able to get 13 installed on my Apple Silicon laptop, and `ActiveDirectoryInteractive` didn't work either.

Comment: I am using ActiveDirectoryMSI as an auth scheme to connect to Azure Synapse SQL Serverless.  I am receiving login timeout expired, probably one time in 10 runs. Any solution? @alexlod